# Toolbar colors overlay

Tags: android, xml, android-toolbar, android-theme, android-styles

I have an app with theme

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AppBarTest" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/main_background</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

And I have toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/app_bar_color">

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

The color is

```
<color name="app_bar_color">#000429</color>
```

And I have two troubles - first is a color of background takes from colorPrimary but i need custom. And second is - nested horizontal padding from nowhere.

Usage of it activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    this.supportActionBar?.displayOptions = ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
    supportActionBar?.setCustomView(R.layout.main_action_bar)
}
```

}

layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]